# Relation between disposition personality in emotional response

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, personality

In "Determinants of Emotion Duration and Underlying Psychological and Neural Mechanisms" by Verduyn et al, the authors discuss various dispositions that account for how long an emotional effect lasts:

- Resilience
- Depression level
- Extraversion and neuroticism

Extraversion and neuroticism are two components of the OCEAN model of personality. How were these two attributes determined to be most important when it comes to dealing with emotions? What is the relation between personality and disposition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two personality factors can be considered as a component of disposition. Two publications established that extraversion and neuroticism as being the most correlated with emotional processing.

In "[Adding Liebe und Arbeit: The Full Five-Factor Model and Well-Being](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247746194_Adding_Liebe_und_Arbeit_The_Full_Five-Factor_Model_and_Well-Being)" from McCrae et al (1991), the authors correlated three measure of weel-being with 429 adult men and women.

> Consistent with previous rescarch, neuroticism was negatively, and 
>   extraversion was positively, related to well-being. Both agreeableness
>   and conscientiousness were also significant independent predictors

In "[The happy personality: a meta-analysis of 137 personality traits and subjective well-being](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9747186)" by DeNeve et al (1998) examine 137 personality constructs across 9 literature search strategies to find determine the effect on positive and negative affect.

> The traits most closely associated with SWB were
>   repressive-defensiveness, trust, emotional stability, locus of
>   control-chance, desire for control, hardiness, positive affectivity,
>   private collective self-esteem, and tension. When personality traits
>   were grouped according to the Big Five factors, Neuroticism was the
>   strongest predictor of life satisfaction, happiness, and negative
>   affect. Positive affect was predicted equally well by Extraversion and
>   Agreeableness.